nodejs process does not continue in screen environment
i have a strange problem, with a nodejs application and screen environment (running in node 22, on a debian linux)
the function running looks more or less like this:
export const downloadfunction = async (
  links: string[]
) => {
  log.info(`Processing ${stateName}`);
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (needsUpdate || overWriteDB) {
      const initialZipFile = await downloadAndUnzip(source, tmpFolder);
      const files = readdirSync(tmpFolder);
      const zipFiles = files.filter(
        (f) => !f.includes(initialZipFile) && f.includes(".zip")
      );
      rmSync(`${tmpFolder}/${initialZipFile}.zip`);
      for (const zipFile of zipFiles) {
        await unzipFile(`${tmpFolder}/${zipFile}`, tmpFolder);
        rmSync(`${tmpFolder}/${zipFile}`, { recursive: true, force: true });
      }
      const gmlFiles = readdirSync(tmpFolder).filter((f) => f.includes(".gml"));
      const processChunk = async (chunk: string[]) => {
        await Promise.all(
          chunk.map(async (file) => {
            try {

              await longrunningfunction();
              try {
                rmSync(`${tmpFolder}/${file}`);
              } catch {}
            } catch (e) {
            }
          })
        );
      };

      for (let i = 0; i < gmlFiles.length; i += chunkSize) {
        const chunk = gmlFiles.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
        await processChunk(chunk);
      }
    }
  }

  return;
};

since it needs to run through thousands of files, i run the whole thing in a screen session on my debian machine. as long as i have the screen session open, it runs perfectly chunk by chunk. when i close the session, the process stops after some minutes or hours (i dont close the session, i detach from it..., ctrl+a - d ) the process stops working. when i reopen the screen session, it just sais: done and the whole nodejs application is closed.
what am i missing here? and how is a screensession different to a direct ssh session?

how do you know the process stops after some time?

when i reconnect to the screen session and the node process stopped with the last line saying "done". the expected behaviour is that (when really done) i get back to a clickable menu in the shell. I also know it because  a lot is missing on the db after running (the process converts and updates data on a database).

Have you also verified that process always completes if you dont close the session. Also, is there a pattern or count of files which it completes before stopping? I also observed that exception catch blocks in processChunk  are having no code. May be putting some debug logs in exception catch blocks of processChunk and also in for loop that calls processChunk could help in confirming that there is no other hidden bug that makes it stop processing? I have not used screen sessions earlier, but just got curious about this question and trying to see if i can point out something.
